# How to get the unique node with out using "contain"

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Was trying to retrieve a value of an attribute of a parent node.

Question: How to get the parent node by matching all the child text using only equal search not the contain search

XML structure:

```
 <Elementstart>
   <Cardstart>
      <Simulate Number="1">
         <One>4</One>
         <Two>2</Two>
         <Three>11</Three>
      </Simulate>
      <Simulate Number="5">
         <One>44</One>
         <Two>22</Two>
         <Three>111</Three>
      </Simulate>
   </Cardstart>
 </Elementstart>
```

1) I need to get the parent  by Query the child elements
Using the following XPATH

```
 //Simulate[contains(One, '4') and contains(Two, '2') and contains(Three,'1')]
```

I got both parent `<Simulate Number="1">` and `<Simulate Number="5">`
However I need to get only the `<Simulate Number="1">` as I have queried with only single digit 2. Is there a way to get only the first one?

Another query is How to use the `equal` or `text()=''` with `and` condition?

Comment: I had tried with the Xpath {//Simulate[contains(One, '4') and contains(Two, '2') and contains(Three,'1')]  } I got both parent <Simulate Number="1"> and <Simulate Number="5"> However I need to get only the <Simulate Number="1"> as I have queried with only single digit 2. Is there a way to get only the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XPath which will return `Simulate` by matching exact value of each of the three child elements :

```
//Simulate[One='4' and Two='2' and Three='11']
```

The result would be `<Simulate Number="1">` element.